# Javascript remove row of a html table is not working in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

My javascript function is not working in Google chrome . I am calling this function using onclick button
my code is here

```
function remove(t)
{
    var orw=t.parentElement.parentElement;      

    document.all('tbl').deleteRow(orw.rowIndex);

}
```

Comment: Does it work in other browsers? Have you checked the console for error messages?

Comment: only in Internet Explorer

Comment: Always try to give proper issue, then only community can help on same.

Comment: Please show your HTML code for reference

Comment: `document.all` is very, very IE-only, and even in IE it's obsoleted in the newest versions. Use `document.getElementById()` instead.

Comment: i solve the problem using getElementById()

Answer (score 0):

use

```
var orw=t.parentElement.parentElement;      


 document.getElementById("tbl").deleteRow(orw.rowIndex);//orw.rowIndex is the row index which you want to remove
```